# How to know if a coordinate is within a shape file in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a set of coordinates (lat and lng) in an excel document. I have also a shape file which shows the different states/province of a country. The shape file contains the geometry field. I would like to merge those 2 together in order to be able to identify how many records are within a province and how much are there in the other province. Any idea how I can do a sum of records if a coordinate is within a shape file boundary/state ?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Tableau?  And is there a reason you're not using the built-in mapping that provides the states / province boundaries for a country?  You should be able to load your coordinates and Tableau will plot them on the map.  And I *think* once you do that, you'll be able to make a table calc for the count of records by state/province.

Comment: @devlincarnate Unfortunately, a table calc can't access the underlying map boundaries to answer his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used python to convert the coordinates to the shapefile projection and looped through each record to find if it is within the bounderies of a polygon or multipolygon. I used python to prepare the data and I would simply plot it in Tableau. This is the way it worked for me. If you want more information about this, don't hesitate to let me know. I will share the python code.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want to use is often called a geospatial join, and it uses the spatial extension to SQL called INTERSECTS. Spatially aware databases like Oracle, PostGIS and SQL Server support the INTERSECTS operator for geometry data types.

Recent versions of Tableau have been adding increasing amounts of support to allow access to spatial database features, in addition to just calling them from custom SQL. Recent versions of Tableau have also added support for calling INTERSECTS in a join condition for geospatial file data sources such as shape files and kml.

So your best bet may to get your excel data file transformed into some geospatially aware format like Shapefile, KML, geojson, an esri geodatabase or put into a geospatially aware database. Then you can join that with your state/province shapefile from Tableau to identify which data points fall within which province boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task. As Tableau is not designed to do spatial analyses. I had to seek alternative solution. I did use Qgis to do actal spatial join. 
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_joins.html

My workflow was to open shapefile and then add another layer from csv. In csv i did have id, lat & lon

After actual spatial join i did export newly created layer attributes to csv
(lat lon id state etc...)

Then use the csv in Tableau if needed